# NetSuite Workflow Formula - Set 'Date' field as today plus 3 days

Tags: netsuite

I'm new to NetSuite and ask your advice on a simple formula. I created a workflow that should populate the 'Due Date' field on my form as today plus 3 days. So if I submit the form on April 11, the 'Due Date' field will populate with April 14.

Does anyone know what the formula should me? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your question is pretty broad. Can you populate the field with a date? Can you populate it with today's date? Can you add 3 days to a date? What *exactly* is the problem where you are stuck?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `to_date({today}) + 3`.